# Show that the probability approaches $0$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The toll booth operator cannot take a break as long as there are cars in her queue. The times between arrivals of cars are independent with mean 5 minutes. It takes her on average 2 minutes to process each customer. These service times are independent for different customers and independent of the arrival times of the cars. Let $p_n$ be the probability that the toll booth operator has had to serve n customers in a row without a break. Show that $p_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

**My Attempt**

I am having trouble getting started on this problem. Should I start by modeling the time between cars as a distribution? Then find the limit of the probability?
Let $X$ denote the time between cars. Then $X\sim Exp(\lambda)$ where $\lambda=\frac{1}{5}$.

I am having trouble fitting the $2$ minute processing time into the model so I can take the limit of the probability.

Comment: To incorporate the processing time into the model, see [M/M/1 queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue).

Comment: I am not sure how to rigorously prove this without invoking the solution to Lindley's integral equation, which is not trivial. In general it is difficult to analyze G/G/1 queues especially with no knowledge of the variance of the interarrival and service times.